# The VS2010 SQL Connection Dialog

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, sqlconnection

I have successfully implemented the VS2010 SQL Connection dialog (downloaded from [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Connection) into a few of my projects now and have been using it without complaint. I have been using it explicitly to connect to SQL Server, and recently I have wanted to test whether the user has checked the 'Save my password' check box, shown below:

[image: VS2010 Connection Dialog]

The `public partial class SqlConnectionUIControl : UserControl, IDataConnectionUIControl` has a private member class called `ControlProperties` which contains all of the accessors to the information I need - but I cannot get to it.

The way this dialog is written is fairly complex and I do not want to go changing there source code if I can help it. Has anybody come across this before and if so, how do I read whether the user has selected the 'Save my password' (accessed in the `SqlConnectionUIControl` class via `public bool SavePassword`) option (or any other for that matter)?

Comment: Well, you could use reflection to retrieve this property. A little unreliable, but will do the trick :) If you'd like, I can post a code snippet for that.

Comment: I would love that dude. Thanks very much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's OK for you to use Reflection in this case, you can dig into the private properties and extract their values. Here is an example (based on the `Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.Sample` project from your link):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DataConnectionDialog dialog = new DataConnectionDialog();
    DataConnectionConfiguration connectionConfig = new DataConnectionConfiguration(null);
    connectionConfig.LoadConfiguration(dialog);

    if (DataConnectionDialog.Show(dialog) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        bool isSavePasswordChecked = IsSavePasswordChecked(dialog);
    }
}

private static bool IsSavePasswordChecked(DataConnectionDialog dialog)
{
    var control = GetPropertyValue("ConnectionUIControl", dialog, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty);
    if (control == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var properties = GetPropertyValue("Properties", control, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
    if (properties == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var savePassword = GetPropertyValue("SavePassword", properties, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty);
    if (savePassword != null && savePassword is bool)
    {
        return (bool)savePassword;
    }

    return false;
}

private static object GetPropertyValue(string propertyName, object target, BindingFlags bindingFlags)
{
    var propertyInfo = target.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName, bindingFlags);
    if (propertyInfo == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return propertyInfo.GetValue(target, null);
}
```

But keep in mind that this approach introduces some versioning issues: if you're going to upgrade the DataConnection dialog library at some point in the future, these properties might not be available in the newer versions.

Comment: Thanks for this. Is this something that you have done yourself with this dialog?

Comment: @Killercam: No, I wrote that just now. I remember using this dialog a while ago, but that task did not involve checking for "Save password" checkbox.

Comment: This is amazing and I had no idea you could use reflection for this kind of thing. I would be amazed to learn how you knew you could do this so quickly!?

Comment: @Killercam: Thanks :) I knew about this approach because I had used it a few times in the past to investigate the behavior of some external libraries.